# What does an "in" generic parameter do?

Tags: c#, generics

Saw this signature today:

`public interface ISomeInterface<in T>`

What impact does the `in` parameter have?

Comment: It's no generic constraint. `out` and `in` are used to mark a generic parameter as co-/contra-variant.

Comment: I think it means that when a class implements that interface e.g. `class A<T> : ISomeInterface`   and another class subclasses B. Then  looking at the interface on the LHS(left hand side), of an assignment  i.e. the static type side,  and the RHS, you can, besides the usual making the Ts the same time, you can make the Ts different in that you can make the dynamic one a superclass. So you can say  `ISomeInterface<B> SomeIntWithB = new MyClass<A>();`  I haven't tried it myself by that's what I glean from Schildt C# Ch18. p558,559

Comment: he also mentions covariance and contravariance with delegates, without generics. The 'in' is as people have mentioned, contravariance. The 'out' used with generics, is covariance.    The word 'out' is also used in a sense that is nothing to do with generics in the sense of out vs ref.  But  in vs out is to do with generics.  Covariance and contravariance can occur without generics too, in the case of delegates without generics which is mentioned in Schildt c# 4.0 ch15 but is still applicable to current c#.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could read about generic [variance and contravariance](http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2010/01/10/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4.0.aspx) introduced in .NET 4.0. The impact that the `in` keyword has on the interface is that it declares it as contravariant meaning that `T` can only be used as input method type. You cannot use it as return type on the methods of this interface. The benefit of this is that you will be able to do things like this (as shown in the aforementioned article):

```
interface IProcessor<in T>  
{  
    void Process(IEnumerable<T> ts);  
}

List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe> { new Giraffe() };  
List<Whale> whales = new List<Whale> { new Whale() };  
IProcessor<IAnimal> animalProc = new Processor<IAnimal>();  
IProcessor<Giraffe> giraffeProcessor = animalProc;  
IProcessor<Whale> whaleProcessor = animalProc;  
giraffeProcessor.Process(giraffes);  
whaleProcessor.Process(whales);
```

Comment: Nice example, particularly since you use a covariant type IEnumerable<T> inside a contravariant type IProcessor<T>.

Answer (score 5):

That signifies generic contravariance. The opposite is covariance (keyword `out`).

What this means is that when an interface is contravariant (`in`), then the interface can be implicitly converted to a generic type when the type parameter inherits T.

Conversely for covariance `out`, the interface can be implicitly converted to a generic type where the type parameter is a 'lesser' type in the type hierarchy.

Comment: You write "where the type parameter that inherits T."   that isn't English, could you please correct that?

Comment: Done, better ? Grammar slips a bit for me at times, since I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Yeah that line is now English.  And where you say "a 'lesser' type"  I think you mean "a 'lower' type".