# Are the keywords "in" and "out" redundant in generic delegates?

Tags: c#

I am wondering why the keywords "in" and "out" are even used in generic delegates, e.g.

```
 public delegate TResult Func1<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
 public delegate TResult Func2<in T1, TResult, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
 public delegate TResult Func3<TResult, T2, T1>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
```

all of them compile with the same result. Clearly, the compiler treats 
all the identifiers inside (....) as "in", and the return type in front
of delegate name as "out", so it is redundant to use "in" and "out"
inside <....>. As a matter of fact, if you use "in" and "out" incorrectly
then the compiler will not compile. So what is the point of having them
in the first place?

Comment: What did you find when you looked at the documentation for that feature, and how did that fail to answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an "in" generic parameter do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723082/what-does-an-in-generic-parameter-do)

Comment: Documentation only talks about the meaning of "in" and "out", and not about the ***NEED*** for explicit keywords. If you need an umbrella when it rains then it not mean that you have to have a big sign ***UMBRELLA*** on it

Comment: `out` has one meaning for method parameters, and another for generic type parameters. `in` has meaning only for generic type parameters. None of those meanings has anything to do with what you seem to think they mean (**"the return type in front of delegate name"*?). Please read the documentation. This is not a matter of specifying which types are for parameters and and which are for the return value.

Comment: "out" may have different meanings for different contexts, however we are talking about one context. My question is why you have "out" for generic delegate when there is no need for it because the context already implies it

Comment: @LolaWecv You made up a story about what `in` and `out` mean in *this* context. That story is totally wrong in *every* context. They're not specifying return and parameter types.

Comment: You seem to think that "out" means "is the return type".  "out" means "may be used in contravariant conversions *because* it is the return type". If you don't understand what covariance and contravariance are, understand those first.

Answer (score 5):

> what is the point of having them in the first place?

To allow the developer to describe their intentions regarding covariance and contravariance of delegate and interface types, and to ensure that the compiler checks the correctness of the expressed intention.

They cannot be *deduced* because (1) there is no general mechanism I'm aware of for making that deduction; feel free to propose one if you like, and (2) because it is a bad user experience when small changes one place invisibly cause far-reaching changes in type compatibility other places.

If this subject interests you then you should read my eleven part series on how we designed and implemented the feature.

Start here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/

The article particularly germane to your question is part seven.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a trivial example:

```
// concatenate the two object parameters with a separator to create a string
Func1<object, object, string> f1 = (s1, s2) => s1 + ":" + s2;
Func3<object, object, string> f3 = (s1, s2) => s1 + ":" + s2;

// this is fine; any string is also an object, so the "in" is satisfies
// the two parameters, and the "out" satisfies the return value - as
// such, the delegate can be implicitly cast using the variance rules
Func1<string, string, object> x1 = f1;

// this is not fine; the assignment is invalid
Func3<string, string, object> x3 = f3;
```

They're not the same; the `in` and `out` have meaning.