# What's the difference between ISomeInterface<in TEntity> and ISomeInterface<out TEntity> in c#

Tags: c#, interface

Whats  the difference between `ISomeInterface<in TEntity>` and `ISomeInterface<out TEntity>` in c#. I saw this while trying to understand my company code. any king of help would be appreciated. Also, I want to know if there is any difference in implementing both.

Comment: Duplicate of [out<T> vs <T> in Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956993/out-t-vs-t-in-generics?)?  Though that answer doesn't specifically talk about `in`.  You can find that one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723082/what-does-an-in-generic-parameter-do).  Both SO questions suggest you read up on [contravariance and covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). @devNull found an even better SO question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Covariant and Contravariant interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp)