# "in" generic modifier interaction with "where" clause

Tags: c#, generics, contravariance

Suppose the following:

```
interface IBase { }
interface IChild : IBase { }
interface IFace<in T> where T : IBase { }
private class MyClass : IFace<IBase> { }

void Do1()
{
    // This is fine
    IFace<IChild> impl = new MyClass();
}

void Do2<T>() where T : IBase
{
    // This is not
    IFace<T> impl = new MyClass();
}
```

Why is that? Isn't `T` in `Do2` guaranteed to inherit from/implement IBase?

Edit: forgot where clause in IFace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does an "in" generic parameter do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723082/what-does-an-in-generic-parameter-do)

Comment: Because the `IBase` that `MyClass` uses may not be a `T`

Comment: What if `IFace<T> impl = (IFace<T>)new MyClass();`?

Comment: Whenever something is 'not fine' there's an error message somewhere. That message should be included in the question so that people trying to help can understand the problem. It's there on the screen and you can share it with us. Please don't post questions like "It doesn't work" or "This is fine but this isn't" when the specific error message is right there.

Answer (score 1):

The following code also won't compile because `T` is not exactly the `IBase`:

```
IFace<IBase> x;
IFace<T> impl = x; // T is IBase, but not always IBase is T
```

It can be some implementation of `IChild`, for instance.
It may be more clear in the following code:

```
IFace<Animal> x;
IFace<Dog> impl = x; // A dog is an animal, but not always an animal is a dog
```

That's why you need an explicit cast:

```
IFace<T> impl = (IFace<T>)new MyClass();
```